# Duplicated cite using apalike

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style, overleaf, apa6

I am using `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`. When I use `\cite{}` a reference that is in the corresponding .bib, the cite appears twice in my article. Does anybody know what is happening?
I am working in overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The information you've posted so far is not sufficient to allow a diagnosis of the situation. Please provide (a lot) more information about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ? Do you load any citation management packages (such as `natbib` or `apacite`)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "appears twice"? When you use `See \cite{jones} for an example` do you get _See (Jones, 2010)(Jones, 2010) for an example_ in your document? Or something else? Or does the citation appear twice in the Bibliography section at the end of the document? Also, does this happen with all citations or just one specific entry from the `.bib` file? If just with one, then how does this entry look in the `.bib` file?